# Android-Cursor stays empty after successfull SQLite-Databasequery

Tags: java, android-sqlite, android-cursor

after 3 Days of searching in the web and trying  different stuff i'm a the end of my knowledge.
I am trying to get data from a Android-SQLitedatabase via a Cursor. The Database is created with this SQLCode:

create table Passwort("ref text primary key, pw text)";

The Buggcode is like this:

public String suchen(String refe) {

```
    String antwort = "";
    open();
    try {
        String rawQuery = "Select * FROM Passwort WHERE ref LIKE \"" + refe
                + "\"";
        // Cursor c= db.query("Passwort", null, DBspalten[0]+"= '"+refe+"'",
        // null, null, null, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
        System.out.println(c.moveToFirst());
        // normaly the "antwort" would  be the second field of the Cursors first entry 
        // as told, the cursors  is always empty
        //antwort = "";
        System.out.println("testausgabe:" + " " + c.getCount());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("anderer Fehler");
    }
    return antwort;
}
```

I inserted via a successfull insert-Statement a entry with ref="test" pw="QqjMs740Mg"
This data is definitive in the Database, I found it via a Eclipse plugin in the Database.
So what is the problem of my Cursor that the activ System.out.println-statment always delivers false, which means there is no Data in the Cursor.

Comment: the version i used for testing was API-10 because my own Smartphone is a little bit older

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String rawQuery = "Select * FROM Passwort WHERE ref LIKE '" + refe + "'";
```

I just replaced the double quotes with single quotes. so the sql query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Passwort WHERE ref LIKE 'your_refe_value'
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: I tryed that before, with the same outcome, meanwhile i found a, solution, but this one has a big disadvantage: i simply change my API-Level of the Emulator from 10 to 14 and it worked, so maybe its a general problem of the implementation under level 10, i remember i had problems with the select befor too, that time the Statment did deliver Data, but not all asked Data.